# Share a local image to facebook with React?

Tags: reactjs, facebook-share

I have a react site that renders different awards for users based on their status. I want the users to be able to share these images on facebook. Basically the idea I had was to use use-react-screenshot to take a screenshot of the component and share this image somehow. However, I know that facebook only lets you share public image urls. Since these awards are different for each user, I can't just upload them all on a site and get the url that way. Is there an api or something I can call that will give me an image url? Or is there an easier way to go about this? Thank you!